# The linkage between R and C++(Rccp)

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Well, I wanna use `R` to call a `C++` function to solve a quadratic programming problem, but the core `C++` function uses other defined functions as well. That's to say, we need to use a whole `C++` project to solve this problem including many `C++` source files and header files. What can I do to call this `C++` function using `R,` can I use the `Rcpp` package as regular?

Comment: What do you mean by "as regular"? What you describe calls for an R package, and Rcpp is very well suited to provide theintetface. Have you read the corresponding Rcpp vignette?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read so much about Rcpp, I just wanna solve the specific problem.

Comment: You know, using R to solve the QP is slow so I wanna use R to call C++ function to solve this problem. As I know, we can construct a C++ file in R and use sourceRcpp to call it. But now I have a C++ project, but I don't know what I should do with R

Comment: Interfacing with existing C/C++ code is one of the prime use cases of Rcpp. Please read at least the introduction and package vignettes. As a first iteration you could use `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()` to start a package, put all the external files into the `src` directory, and add a `cpp` file using Rcpp that calls the specific C++ function. This should work if the C++ project is simple. If it is complex, it might be easier to build a static library out of it. There are many examples on CRAN for both approaches. Is the QP code you want to interface available somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot!